# Fetching data from String and populating a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a string with a format that looks like this:

```
Recipe{id=someID, title=someTitle, image='LINK', usedIngredientCount=SomeNumber, missedIngredientCount=SomeNumber2, likes=SomeNumber3}Recipe{id=someID, title=someTitle, image='LINK', usedIngredientCount=SomeNumber, missedIngredientCount=SomeNumber2, likes=SomeNumber3}
```

Note that in the example above the string contains 2 Recipes, but it can actually contain any number of recipes.
I want to put whatever number of recipes I have in a RecyclerView, and I am wondering what is the easiest way of doing it. What I am thinking is splitting the main string into substrings everytime I find the word `Recipe` then extracting `someID` `LINK` `SomeNumber1` `SomeNumber2` `SomeNumber3` from every substring and finally populating the RecyclerView using these values.

Could you please help me either convert my idea into code or come up with easier ways of doing it?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    public RecyclerAdapter adapterD;
    ArrayList<String> id;
    ArrayList<String> title;
    ArrayList<String> image;
    ArrayList<String> usedIngredientCount;
    ArrayList<String> missedIngredientCount;
    ArrayList<String> likes;

    void onCreate()
    {
    id= new ArrayList<>();
    title = new ArrayList<>();
    image = new ArrayList<>();
    likes = new ArrayList<>(); 
    usedIngredientCount= new ArrayList<>();
    missedIngredientCount = new usedIngredientCountArrayList<>();

    // your recipe string here
    String recipe = "id title image usedIngredientCount missedIngredientCount likes" ;

    // break the string 
    dataSplit(recipe)

    // call the recyclerview adapter
            recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            adapterD = new RecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, id, title, image, 
                              usedIngredientCount, missedIngredientCount, likes);


            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterD);

    }

     void dataSplit(String recipe)
    {
        // Split String when there is space
        String parts[] = recipe.split(" ");

        id.add( parts[0] );
        title.add(parts[1]);
        image.add(parts[2]);
        usedIngredientCount.add(parts[3]);
        missedIngredientCount.add(parts[4]);
        likes.add(parts[5]);
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't this work if the string had this format? : 
`"id title image usedIngredientCount missedIngredientCount likes"` yet my string has this format:
`Recipe{id=someID, title=someTitle, image='LINK', usedIngredientCount=SomeNumber, missedIngredientCount=SomeNumber2, likes=SomeNumber3}Recipe{id=someID, title=someTitle, image='LINK', usedIngredientCount=SomeNumber, missedIngredientCount=SomeNumber2, likes=SomeNumber3}`